# Present view controller nil key error

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have my app just segue screens if the login credentials have been verified, but for some reason upon segue there is a fatal error.  Below is the error I have been running into:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: key cannot be nil'
***
```

below is the code that I am running:

```
if user!.isEmailVerified {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileView") as! ProfileView
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)                    
}
```

The print statement before the segue prints, but not the one after it.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and give the exact line.  Could be in the ProfileView init or other code.

Comment: Please show your viewDidLoad from ProfileView. It could be an exception there.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're creating an instance of a view controller and presenting it is correct if the view controller is on the same storyboard. The problem is happening somewhere else, probably with something asynchronous. Make sure isEmailVerified is working as expected.

Comment: they are in the same storyboard, and when I delete the 2 lines for the segue it runs without error

Comment: is this happening after viewDidLoad()?

Comment: No, its in an IBAction function called on the button click

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Check if the user exists: `guard let user = User, user.isEmailVerified else {return}`

2.Use app delegate rather than storyboard.

```
guard let rootController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileView") as? ProfileView else {return}
self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: tried this as well, still a fatal error on the `self.present()` call

Comment: You have the ID in StoryboardID and restoration ID right? Instead of `self.present()` , try this `let appDelegateTemp = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
appDelegateTemp?.window?.rootViewController = yourProfileVC`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileView")
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Go to your Story Board and select your ProfileView controller.  Then, in Identity Inspector confirm you have selected ProfileView for that View Controller.  In my example below I've subclassed ActionViewController.

[image]

Comment: Just updated my answer based on your response.  Please check it out.